# Detect and delete line break directly out of mysql query

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation, detect, subject

im trying to detect and delete a line break out of a subject (called **m.subject**) mail information retrieved via CONCAT out of a mysql database.
That said, the linebreak may or may not occur in the subject and therefore must be detected.

My query looks like this:

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -h $DB_HOST -D $TARGET -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PW -N -r -e "SELECT CONCAT(m.one,';',m.two,';',m.three,';',m.subject,';',m.four';',m.five,';',(SELECT CONCAT(special_one) FROM special_$SQL_TABLE WHERE msg_id = m.six ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)) FROM mails_$SQL_TABLE m WHERE m.rtime BETWEEN $START AND $END AND m.seven = 1 AND m.eight IN (2);"
```

I tried to delete it afterwards, but getting in performance trouble due to several while operations on all lines already. Is there an easy way to detect and cut it directly via the CONCAT buildup? It is crucial to retrieve only one line after extraction for me.

Updating/changing the database is not an option for me, as I only want to read the current state.

Comment: What about something like `SELECT REPLACE(subject, '\n', '') FROM Table;`

Comment: But what if one subject doesnt has a \n in it? Is there an if option in mysql at all?

Comment: Then it won't replace anything.

Comment: That would be a nice solution. Are you so kind and help me assambling the relevant part in conjunction with my recent query?

Comment: If you let me share a personal remark, even Chuck Norris would find it daunting to develop SQL queries in a single-line command-line parameter inside a shell command. You have my respect.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. Pretty amusing actually, im starting to build a another while loop, only to kill linebreaks before further processes but after the above stated query. Its a pain because my output is kinda big, talking in line counts.